# Unite.vim preview navigation

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, unite.vim

I'm using Vim with the Unite plugin. How to prevent jump to first line in unite preview, when cursor is in last position and key down <kbd>J</kbd> is pressed and otherwise jump from first line to last line, when key up <kbd>K</kbd> is pressed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not too hard, given the Unite docs. Lines for your `vimrc`:

```
augroup my_unite
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType unite call s:unite_my_settings()
augroup END

function! s:unite_my_settings()
    nmap <buffer><expr> j line('.') == line('$') ? '' : '<Plug>(unite_loop_cursor_down)'
    nmap <buffer><expr> k line('.') == 1 ? '' : '<Plug>(unite_loop_cursor_up)'
endfunction
```

Comment: Thx for answer, this is work! But i found more simple solution: 
https://github.com/Shougo/unite.vim/issues/1023

Comment: Yep, the author always knows best :)

Answer (score 1):

You can find out if there is a mapping on your <kbd>J</kbd> by typing

```
:map j
```

If there is, and you do not like, you can unmap it by putting this into your vimrc

```
autocmd VimEnter * unmap j
```

It should do the trick (the same for the <kbd>K</kbd>).

There is also another way (`:help after-directory`) but I prefer this one.

Comment: Thx for answer, but this not help.. unite don't provide built-in command for key up/down without loop to start/end..